# построить график функции sin(x)^sgn(sin(100x)) на отрезке [-10:10] с шагом 0.1

Tags: matlab

Понимаю, что задачка детская но не могу понять в чём ошибка.

```
    x=-10:0.1:10;
y=sin(x)^sgn(sin(100*x))
plot(x,y)
title('График функции cos(3x)')
xlabel('Ось X')
ylabel('Ось Y')
legend('y=cos(3x)')
grid on
```

Answer (score 0):

Вторая строчка должна быть такая:

```
y=sin(x).^sign(sin(100*x))
```

Во-первых, не `sgn`, а `sign`, а во-вторых, не `^`, а `.^`. Крышка без точки это операция возведения матрицы в степень через матричное произведение. Здесь же надо поэлементно возвести массив `sin(x)` в степени, задаваемые массивом  `sign(sin(100*x))`, поэтому следует использовать операцию поэлементного возведения в степень `.^`.